# Formalization of $17\mid 77a+1$

Tags: divisibility

I was solving a math problem when I came across this Question:

> When is $17 \mid 77a+1$ With $a\in \mathbb N^*$

It’s easy to see that there’s infinitely many of values of $a$, you can’t try a little bit with this but you will end up with these values :
$$a\in \{15,32,49,66,...\}=A$$
In this set any number it’s equal to the previous one $+17$ .
I’ve found a relation with this set and the set contains all numbers divisible by $17$, let’s call it $D_{17}$
$$D_{17} =\{17,34,51,68,...\}$$
You can see that if $n \in D_{17} \iff n-2\in A$ And if $n\in A \iff n+2 \in D_{17}$.

My question is why $2$ appeared here, does there exist an equation that when we solve it we will get this $2$?

Comment: Not following.  The solution to $77a\equiv -1 \pmod {17}$ is $a\equiv 15\pmod {17}$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: To solve it mentally, note that $77\equiv 9\pmod {17}$ and that the inverse of $9\pmod {17}$ is clearly $2$. ( Is that the $2$ you are asking about?).  It follows at once that the solution to $77a\equiv -1$ is $a\equiv -2\equiv 15$   (all congruences $\pmod {17}$).

Comment: Hang on i don’t know how to solve linear congruence .

Comment: Ok...my second comment shows you how to solve this one in particular,  Alternatively, with numbers as small as $17$, trial and error is an easy way to solve them.  Nothing wrong with doing it that way, though of course it's a terrible method for dealing with very large numbers.

Comment: For a general technique for this class of problem, look up "Euclid's algorithm".

Comment: Where should I use it in this problem ?-@aschepler

Comment: $17 \mid 77a+1$ if and only if there is an integer $k$ where $77a + 17k = -1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$77a+1\equiv 17 \bmod 17$$
$$77a\equiv -1 \bmod 17$$
$$9a\equiv -1 \bmod 17$$
The modular inverse of $9\bmod 17$ is $2$ therefore
$$a\equiv -2 \bmod 17$$
that is $$a=17n-2;\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N^*}$$

Comment: So there’s no way you can get an answer without use modular arithmetic ?

Comment: @Yassir Yes, there is. When you wrote $$a\in \{15,32,49,66,...\}=A$$ $A$ is the set of multiple of $17$ less $2$ that is the same as $a=17n-2$

Answer (score 0):

**Divisibility by $17$**.- A number $n$ is divisible by $17$ if, subtracting from the number without the units digit the units digit multiplied by $5$, the result is equal to a multiple of $17$.

When $17|77a+1?$. You have $77a+1=(4\cdot17+9)a+1$ so you need $17|9a+1$

Consider $9a+1\equiv\alpha_1\pmod{10}$ According with the criterium above we make

$(9a+1-\alpha_1)-5\alpha_1\equiv0\pmod{17}$ and iterating the procedure until the congruence could be clearly seen to be true or false, we have the answer.